# NSMutableArray and ARC

Tags: nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to add an object to an NSMutableArray with code like this:

```
Item *newItem = [[Item alloc] init];
[self.theArray addObject:newItem];
```

If I remember correctly, back in the old retain/release days I wouldn't have to worry about the `newItem` variable going out of scope, because the object would receive a `retain` when it was added to the array, and so wouldn't be deallocated.

But I'm using ARC now, and the object disappears. The array itself is fine, and the other objects it contained already are not affected. So I suspect that my `newItem` is being automatically deallocated for some reason.

Can someone give me an idea about what is going on here, and how I could fix it?

Comment: An array can't hold `nil` objects. Is the object in the array after you've called `addObject:`?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in the debug window in Xcode. All of its attributes (NSStrings) are intact too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Item *newItem = [[Item alloc] init];

// This line is the same as this
//
// __strong Item *newItem = [[Item alloc] init];
//
// the newItem variable has strong reference of the Item object.
// So the reference count of the Item object is 1.

[self.theArray addObject:newItem];

// Now theArray has strong reference of the Item object.
// So the reference count of the Item object is 2.
```

The reference count of the Item object is 2, thus the Item object will not be released. If your code had a scope like the following,

```
{
    Item *newItem = [[Item alloc] init];
    [self.theArray addObject:newItem];
}
```

It doesn't affect the Item object.

```
{
    Item *newItem = [[Item alloc] init];
    [self.theArray addObject:newItem];
    // the reference count of the Item object is 2 as I said.
}
// The scope of the newItem variable was ended.
// So the lifetime of the newItem variable was ended,
// then the strong reference by the newItem was gone.
// Thus the reference count of the Item object was reduced from 2 to 1.
```

The reference count of the Item object is 1, thus the Item object will not be released as well.

Comment: I have discovered that the `newItem` object is not being deallocated: it is just being removed from the array. I have no idea why this is happening. I've stepped through the code and there is no `removeLastObject` method being performed on that array.

Comment: There are a lot of methods to remove or replace an item from NSMutableArray other than removeLastObject.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was wrong. It had nothing to do with allocations. What was happening was the awakeFromNib method was being called again when a table view was being reloaded. Of course that reset all kinds of things, making stuff disappear.